# Crashing on some devices when inserting objects to realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have an application that uses Realm as the internal storage extensively, I recently run into a problem that appears to happen in some devices but not all devices. I did open an [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/6315), but since the app is crashing quite seriously, I am hoping I could also get some insight from here.

Each time I tried to insert a message into realm, it crashed. I was using 3.18.0 at first and encounter this problem, then I saw there is a bug mentioned in [#6268](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/6268) and [#6257](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/6257). I upgrade to version 3.20.0 and it seems that the problem still appeared.  Below is a reference for the error log.

The log:

[image]

Another log:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019ba1e0dc 0x19b9fb000 + 143580
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019ba9b9b0 0x19ba95000 + 27056
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019b977f4c 0x19b91d000 + 372556
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019b977eb4 0x19b91d000 + 372404
4   Realm                           0x0000000106023918 realm::util::terminate+ 3176728 (char const*, char const*, long) + 0
5   Realm                           0x0000000106023be4 realm::util::terminate_internal+ 3177444 (std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) + 264
6   Realm                           0x0000000106023d5c realm::util::terminate+ 3177820 (char const*, char const*, long, std::initializer_list<realm::util::Printable>&&) + 328
7   Realm                           0x0000000105d4db38 realm::Column<long long>::do_erase(unsigned long, unsigned long, bool) + 203576 (column.hpp:1606)
8   Realm                           0x00000001060b60e0 realm::sync::TableInfoCache::get_table_info+ 3776736 (unsigned long) const + 1908
9   Realm                           0x00000001060b6bf8 realm::sync::create_object_with_primary_key+ 3779576 (realm::sync::TableInfoCache const&, realm::Table&, realm::util::Optional<long long>) + 52
10  Realm                           0x0000000105d9a400 realm::Object realm::Object::create<objc_object* __strong, RLMAccessorContext>(RLMAccessorContext&, std::__1::shared_ptr<realm::Realm> const&, realm::ObjectSchema const&, objc_object* __strong, bool, bool, unsigned long, realm::BasicRow<realm::Table>*) + 517120 (object_accessor.hpp:0)
11  Realm                           0x0000000105d9a090 RLMAddObjectToRealm + 516240 (RLMObjectStore.mm:152)
12  <myapp>                         0x0000000104b4b4a4 MyClass.insertRealmMessage(_:scrollToBottom:) + 357540 (MyClass+Realm.swift:0)
13  <myapp>                         0x0000000104c04010 specialized MyClass.handle(_:something:) + 1114128 (MyClass+Socket.swift:0)
14  <myapp>                         0x0000000104bec4a0 MyClass.process(_:didReceive:) + 1016992 (MyClass.swift:0)
15  <myapp>                         0x0000000104ba84b8 closure #1 in MyClass.stream(_:didReceive:) + 738488 (MyClass.swift:0)
16  <myapp>                         0x0000000104b0c8cc thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 100556 (<compiler-generated>:0)
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019b8c0a38 0x19b861000 + 391736
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019b8c17d4 0x19b861000 + 395220
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019b8a19e4 0x19b861000 + 264676
20  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019be11ec0 0x19bd68000 + 696000
21  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019be0cdf8 0x19bd68000 + 675320
22  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019be0c354 0x19bd68000 + 672596
23  GraphicsServices                0x000000019e00c79c 0x19e002000 + 42908
24  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c83f7b68 0x1c7b3d000 + 9153384
25  <myapp>                         0x0000000104afbcd0 main + 31952 (User.swift:29)
26  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019b8d28e0 0x19b8d1000 + 6368
```

Another log:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019ba1e0dc 0x19b9fb000 + 143580
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019ba9b9b0 0x19ba95000 + 27056
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019b977f4c 0x19b91d000 + 372556
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019b977eb4 0x19b91d000 + 372404
4   Realm                           0x00000001018f3918 realm::util::terminate+ 3176728 (char const*, char const*, long) + 0
5   Realm                           0x00000001018f3be4 realm::util::terminate_internal+ 3177444 (std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) + 264
6   Realm                           0x00000001018f3d5c realm::util::terminate+ 3177820 (char const*, char const*, long, std::initializer_list<realm::util::Printable>&&) + 328
7   Realm                           0x000000010161db38 realm::Column<long long>::do_erase(unsigned long, unsigned long, bool) + 203576 (column.hpp:1606)
8   Realm                           0x00000001019860e0 realm::sync::TableInfoCache::get_table_info+ 3776736 (unsigned long) const + 1908
9   Realm                           0x0000000101986bf8 realm::sync::create_object_with_primary_key+ 3779576 (realm::sync::TableInfoCache const&, realm::Table&, realm::util::Optional<long long>) + 52
10  Realm                           0x000000010166a400 realm::Object realm::Object::create<objc_object* __strong, RLMAccessorContext>(RLMAccessorContext&, std::__1::shared_ptr<realm::Realm> const&, realm::ObjectSchema const&, objc_object* __strong, bool, bool, unsigned long, realm::BasicRow<realm::Table>*) + 517120 (object_accessor.hpp:0)
11  Realm                           0x000000010166a090 RLMAddObjectToRealm + 516240 (RLMObjectStore.mm:152)
12  <myapp>                         0x000000010047ebb0 MyClass.handle(realmMessage:shouldGenerateAutoIncrement:) + 207792 (MyClass.swift:0)
13  <myapp>                         0x0000000100482588 specialized MyClass.handle(_:chat:) + 222600 (MyClass.swift:0)
14  <myapp>                         0x00000001005444a0 MyClass.function(_:didReceive:) + 1016992 (MyClass.swift:0)
15  <myapp>                         0x00000001005004b8 closure #1 in MyClass.strem(_:didReceive:) + 738488 (MyClass.swift:0)
16  <myapp>                         0x00000001004648cc thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 100556 (<compiler-generated>:0)
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019b8c0a38 0x19b861000 + 391736
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019b8c17d4 0x19b861000 + 395220
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019b8a19e4 0x19b861000 + 264676
20  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019be11ec0 0x19bd68000 + 696000
21  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019be0cdf8 0x19bd68000 + 675320
22  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019be0c354 0x19bd68000 + 672596
23  GraphicsServices                0x000000019e00c79c 0x19e002000 + 42908
24  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c83f7b68 0x1c7b3d000 + 9153384
25  <myapp>                         0x0000000100453cd0 main + 31952 (User.swift:29)
26  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019b8d28e0 0x19b8d1000 + 6368
```

### Steps to Reproduce

I can't actually reproduce the problem, it seems that it only happens to the device that is previously installed and update to the new version, I did try to reinstall older versions of the app and simulate the upgrade process, still no result.

Nearly each of the **INSERT** actions of the message object would result in a crash according to my clients. 
It could happen anywhere in the app that does such a thing, below is some example.

Example One:

```
realm.beginWrite()
conversation.unread += 1

 realm.add(message, update: Realm.UpdatePolicy.all)
 // Update Conversation Timestamp
 conversation.lastMessageTimestamp = message.timestamp

 do {
     try realm.commitWrite()
 } catch let error {
     log.debug("Unable to create Message")
     log.debug(error.localizedDescription)
     return
 }
```

Example Two:

```
realm.beginWrite()
realm.add(newRealmMessage, update: Realm.UpdatePolicy.error)
// Update Conversation Timestamp
if let conversation = newRealmMessage.conversation {
    conversation.lastMessageTimestamp = newRealmMessage.timestamp
}

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    /*Some UI Modification*/
}

commit()
```

There are other places that I do similar things and seem to be producing the same result.

Comment: are you sure that the DB schema is same on all the test devices?

Comment: because what happen is you make a DB schema change then try to run new build on a previously test device which already have that app with old DB scheme, then the application crashes.

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed, thank you for your reply. The schema is always the same in terms of the number of fields among all the test devices, I am not sure if the sequence of the attributes would affect the arrangement of the columns (I don't think that matters, right?). 

The last time I made an adjustment on this model is almost one year back, I did update the schema according to the migration guidelines.

Comment: Just added two more symbolicated logs, please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Encryption?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce No, I did not. I have a question, since each message would contain a `Conversation` object which is also stored in Realm. The `Conversation` object had one new field in the previous update. The field is called 'lastMessageTimestamp' and was set as the same value as the field 'timestamp' in the conversation object. I use the following syntax `newObject['lastMessageTimestam'] = oldObject['timestamp']` to migrate. Would there be any chance this migration may cause the above error? Thank you.